# Not getting correct output python

Tags: python

Trying tp write a program to display up to 40 hours as regular time and anything over that as overtime.

Currently getting an output that takes an input over 40 and prints the input -1 as regular time, and 1 as overtime. Can't seem to figure out where I went wrong.

```
def data():
    wage = float(input('What is your payrate? '))
    while wage < 7 or wage > 50:
        print('Invalid input. Wage must be between $7.00 and $51.00. Please try again.')
        rate = float(input('What is your payrate? '))
    hours = float(input('How many hours were worked? '))
    while hours < 8 or hours > 86:
        print('Invalid input. Hours worked must be between 8 and 86. Please try again.')
        hours = float(input('How many hours were worked? '))
    return hours, wage

def timeCalc(hours):
    if hours <= 40:
        return[hours, False]
    else:
        othour = hours - 40
        return[othour, True]

def payCalc(hours, wage):
    if hours[1]:
        othours = hours[1]
        otpay = othours * (wage * 1.5)
        regularpay = 40 * wage
        return otpay, regularpay, othours
    else:
        return None

def main():
    hours, wage = data()
    if payCalc(timeCalc(hours), wage) == None:
        print('      Payroll Information      ')
        print('Pay Rate: $%.2f' % wage)
        print('Regular Hours: %.0f' % hours)
        print('Overtime Hours: 0')
        print('Regular pay: $%.2f' % (hours * wage))
        print('Overtime pay: $0.00')
        print('')
        print('Total pay: $%.2f' % (hours * wage))
    else:
        otpay, regularpay, othours = payCalc(timeCalc(hours), wage,)
        print('      Payroll Information      ')
        print('Pay Rate: $%.2f' % wage)
        print('Regular Hours: %.0f' % (hours - othours))
        print('Overtime Hours: %.0f' % othours)
        print('Regular pay: $%.2f' % (hours * wage))
        print('Overtime pay: $%.2f' % otpay)
        print('Total pay: $%.2f' % (regularpay + otpay))

main()
```

Output looks like this (I added spaces for a bit of clarity):

```
What is your payrate? 11.5
How many hours were worked? 48
  Payroll Information      
Pay Rate:        $11.50
Regular Hours:   47
Overtime Hours:  1
Regular pay:     $552.00
Overtime pay:    $17.25
Total pay:       $477.25
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you correct the indentation of your code?

Comment: See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Is the output not correct? Which part of it? Can you reduce the question and code to only be about the part which isn't right?

Comment: `rate = float(input(`... You never use `rate`, only `wage`

Answer (score 0):

In function payCalc you need to write `othours = hours[0]`  instead of `othours = hours[1]` to get number of hours (as now it gives you True or False values in numbers)

```
def data():
    wage = float(input('What is your payrate? '))
    while wage < 7 or wage > 50:
        print('Invalid input. Wage must be between $7.00 and $51.00. Please try again.')
        rate = float(input('What is your payrate? '))
    hours = float(input('How many hours were worked? '))
    while hours < 8 or hours > 86:
        print('Invalid input. Hours worked must be between 8 and 86. Please try again.')
        hours = float(input('How many hours were worked? '))
    return hours, wage

def timeCalc(hours):
        if hours <= 40:
            return[hours, False]
        else:
            othour = hours - 40
            return[othour, True]

def payCalc(hours, wage):
    if hours[1]:
        othours = hours[0] # Change Code here
        otpay = othours * (wage * 1.5)
        regularpay = 40 * wage
        return otpay, regularpay, othours
    else:
        return None

def main():
    hours, wage = data()
    if payCalc(timeCalc(hours), wage) == None:
        print('      Payroll Information      ')
        print('Pay Rate: $%.2f' % wage)
        print('Regular Hours: %.0f' % hours)
        print('Overtime Hours: 0')
        print('Regular pay: $%.2f' % (hours * wage))
        print('Overtime pay: $0.00')
        print('')
        print('Total pay: $%.2f' % (hours * wage))
    else:
        otpay, regularpay, othours = payCalc(timeCalc(hours), wage,)
        print('      Payroll Information      ')
        print('Pay Rate: $%.2f' % wage)
        print('Regular Hours: %.0f' % (hours - othours))
        print('Overtime Hours: %.0f' % othours)
        print('Regular pay: $%.2f' % (hours * wage))
        print('Overtime pay: $%.2f' % otpay)
        print('Total pay: $%.2f' % (regularpay + otpay))

main()
```

Here is the output

```
What is your payrate? 50

How many hours were worked? 50

Payroll Information      
Pay Rate: $50.00
Regular Hours: 40
Overtime Hours: 10
Regular pay: $2500.00
Overtime pay: $750.00
Total pay: $2750.00
```

Hope this will work !!

Answer (score 0):

payCalc function ,change if hours[1] to if hours[0]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding:utf-8

'''黄哥Python'''


def data():
    wage = float(input('What is your payrate? '))
    while wage < 7 or wage > 50:
        print('Invalid input. Wage must be between $7.00 and $51.00. Please try again.')
        rate = float(input('What is your payrate? '))
    hours = float(input('How many hours were worked? '))
    while hours < 8 or hours > 86:
        print('Invalid input. Hours worked must be between 8 and 86. Please try again.')
        hours = float(input('How many hours were worked? '))
    return hours, wage


def timeCalc(hours):
    if hours <= 40:
        return[hours, False]
    else:
        othour = hours - 40
        print('****',othour)
        return[othour, True]


def payCalc(hours, wage):
    if hours[0]:
        othours = hours[0]
        otpay = othours * (wage * 1.5)
        regularpay = 40 * wage
        return otpay, regularpay, othours
    else:
        return None


def main():
    hours, wage = data()
    if payCalc(timeCalc(hours), wage) is None:
        print('      Payroll Information      ')
        print('Pay Rate: $%.2f' % wage)
        print('Regular Hours: %.0f' % hours)
        print('Overtime Hours: 0')
        print('Regular pay: $%.2f' % (hours * wage))
        print('Overtime pay: $0.00')
        print('')
        print('Total pay: $%.2f' % (hours * wage))
    else:
        otpay, regularpay, othours = payCalc(timeCalc(hours), wage,)
        print('      Payroll Information      ')
        print('Pay Rate: $%.2f' % wage)
        print('Regular Hours: %.0f' % (hours - othours))
        print('Overtime Hours: %.0f' % othours)
        print('Regular pay: $%.2f' % (hours * wage))
        print('Overtime pay: $%.2f' % otpay)
        print('Total pay: $%.2f' % (regularpay + otpay))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


python3 zh574.py
What is your payrate? 11.5
How many hours were worked? 48
**** 8.0
**** 8.0
      Payroll Information
Pay Rate: $11.50
Regular Hours: 40
Overtime Hours: 8
Regular pay: $552.00
Overtime pay: $138.00
Total pay: $598.00
localhost:python hjzaaa$
```